How do drive 1.4in display on orangepi?
I've setup my orangepi with debian 11 (bullseye) and now I'm trying to connect this display
The display turns on, but is all white and when I run the code shown below I see this

const sclk = new Gpio(11, 'out'); // SPI clock pin
^
TypeError: Gpio is not a constructor

at file:///home/orangepi/app/lcd.js:4:14

I haven't run any displays or anything before, so I'm even sure really where to start.  Can idea of what I should try next?
import pkg from 'orange-pi-gpio';
const { Gpio } = pkg;

const sclk = new Gpio(11, 'out'); // SPI clock pin
const mosi = new Gpio(10, 'out'); // SPI data pin
const cs = new Gpio(8, 'out');    // Chip select
const dc = new Gpio(25, 'out');   // Data/Command control
const rst = new Gpio(27, 'out');  // Reset
const bl = new Gpio(24, 'out');   // Backlight

const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

(async () => {
  try {
    // Initialize the display
    await rst.write(0);
    await delay(100);
    await rst.write(1);
    await delay(100);

    // Send initialization commands to the display
    await sendCommand(0x01); // Software reset
    await delay(150);
    await sendCommand(0x11); // Sleep out
    await delay(500);
    await sendCommand(0x29); // Display on

    // Display "Hello World"
    await displayText("Hello World");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error initializing display:', error);
  }
})();

const sendCommand = async (command) => {
  await dc.write(0); // Command mode
  await cs.write(0); // Select the display
  await spiWrite(command);
  await cs.write(1); // Deselect the display
};

const sendData = async (data) => {
  await dc.write(1); // Data mode
  await cs.write(0); // Select the display
  await spiWrite(data);
  await cs.write(1); // Deselect the display
};

const spiWrite = async (data) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    await sclk.write(0);
    await mosi.write((data & 0x80) ? 1 : 0);
    data <<= 1;
    await sclk.write(1);
  }
};

const displayText = async (text) => {
  const font = {
    'H': [0x7C, 0x12, 0x12, 0x7C], // Example font data for 'H'
    'e': [0x38, 0x54, 0x54, 0x08], // Example font data for 'e'
    'l': [0x00, 0x7E, 0x00, 0x00], // Example font data for 'l'
    'o': [0x38, 0x44, 0x44, 0x38], // Example font data for 'o'
    'W': [0x7C, 0x20, 0x10, 0x7C], // Example font data for 'W'
    'r': [0x7C, 0x08, 0x04, 0x04], // Example font data for 'r'
    'd': [0x38, 0x44, 0x44, 0x7C], // Example font data for 'd'
    ' ': [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]  // Example font data for ' '
  };

  for (const char of text) {
    const charData = font[char];
    if (charData) {
      for (const byte of charData) {
        await sendData(byte);
      }
    }
  }
};


Where did you get those first two lines of code - this very question is the ONLY Google result containing them.  The examples I can find of using this module all start with const Gpio = require('orange-pi-gpio'); instead (I'm not enough of a JS expert to know what the difference is).

it's to import commonjs into a modules project.

Drop the unknown driver in user space and use one of what kernel already provides. You will need to tweak Device Tree to enable there, but after it will be either fully functional DRM or framebuffer. Pleas, do not reinvent the wheel!

FWIW, here is the example how to enable it: https://github.com/notro/panel-mipi-dbi/wiki.
